# How to combine multiple conditions in filters

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created a table and a search box. I'm trying to filter the table rows based on the value that user enters in the search box. I'm using angular 4 framework.

When I set the filter conditions individually it works but doesn't works when combined.

Below filter works correctly:

```
return requests.filter(function(request){
   return request.requestedBy.indexOf(value)> -1;
});
```

But this doesn't works:

```
return requests.filter(function(request){
   return request.requestedBy.indexOf(value) + request.client.toLowerCase().indexOf(value)> -1;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> Used `OR` conditional operator

```
return requests.filter(function(request){
   return request.requestedBy.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1 || request.client.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be an AND?

Comment: `AND` operator requires the same value to be present in both the columns but in my case the value might not be present, so I'm using `OR` operator.

Comment: In that case, testing whether the sum of the two `indexOf()` calls is greater than `-2` would have worked, too. Using `||` as above is much more readable/maintainable, however.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that it's your own answer, it depends on the case of course. :)